# SEO Ajax problems

Tags: seo, ajax

I'm trying to improve my SEO for my backbone/Ajax website. I have followed all the guidelines so far :

- Included the meta fragment tag
- The website delivers an html snapshot when ?_escaped_fragment_= is crawled

I then indexed my pages with "Fetch as Google bot" and send it to the index. The pages get listed correctly but after 1 or 2 days they get listed in a wrong way - that means, that not the ajax content is crawled but only my standard meta-description and meta-tags.

Here is how you can reproduce it:

- go to Google and enter "[eese.com/story](https://www.google.nl/#q=eese.com%2Fstory)"

You should see some stories and one story (`eese.com/story/172025`) is crawled in a wrong way.

Image of searchresults:

[image: Number 5 delivers a wrong result here]

Number 5 delivers a wrong result here (a result I don't want). It should have the correct title and description but instead has the standard meta-description and title.

My guess would be, that the website took to long to get crawled and the crawler aborted.

Answer (score 1):

This might not be what you want to hear but Google will eventually deprecate this escaped fragment for crawling. Why? Because they'll be able to crawl Javascript itself even more than it already can. Take a look at this study released just this past week:[How Googlebot Crawls Javascript](http://searchengineland.com/tested-googlebot-crawls-javascript-heres-learned-220157).

Consider using HTML5, CSS3, and the browsers pushState (or History APi) to achieve indexation with Ajax. [Here is a walkthrough](http://artsy.github.io/blog/2012/06/25/replacing-hashbang-routes-with-pushstate/) specifically on this topic when using backbone.

Comment: That is really good to hear. No worries - the implementation took me only one day so not a big deal. I haven't tested my website without snapshot but i will try that. Thanks for the hint ;)

Comment: @David Garcia, that article does not mention content/data injection from ajax calls. The article instead to focus on less drastic changes, meta tags, image content (not from ajax)

Do you know any info about google indexing ajax rendered content?